# Как заполнить область в байте?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, битовые-операции

Допустим, есть байт `0b00001000`, для удобства разделю: `0 b 0000 - 1000`

Как заполнить область в байте своим числом?

Вот пример, с 1 по 4 бит надо записать `0011`, выйдет:

> 0 b 000**0 - 011**0

Или с 0 по 1 надо записать `11`, выйдет:

> 0 b 0000 - 10**11**

Comment: Ну bit field'ы же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int from = 3; // начиная с 4-го бита
    unsigned int to = 6;  // по 6 бит
    unsigned int val = 11; // записать это значение
    const int BIT_COUNT = sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT;

    std::bitset<BIT_COUNT> x(555); // исходное число
    std::bitset<BIT_COUNT> v(val); 
    std::bitset<BIT_COUNT> m(0); // битовая маска

    std::cout << "x     = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value = " << v << std::endl;


    m.flip();
    m <<= to - from + 1;
    m.flip();
    m <<= from;
    m.flip();

    std::cout << "mask  = " << m << std::endl;

    x  = x & m;
    v <<= from;
    x = x | v;

    std::cout << "res   = " << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Именно это мне и нужно было, спасибо

Answer (score 4):

1. Делаем маску на нужные биты (например для 2345 битов - 11100001)
2. Обнуляем старые биты используя AND по маске, получим 0 на их месте
3. Подготавливаем новые биты (используем смещение вверх для позиционирования)
4. Записываем новые биты используя OR

Comment: А как создать маску числа которое пришло в функцию? Для 3 это будет 11, а вот число 6 занимает уже больше ячеек - 111, число 20 будет занимать пять ячеек, и маска для него будет - 11111

Comment: @Fanrin Если вам нужно узнать длину десятичного числа в битах, то это уже другой вопрос

Comment: Этот вопрос как бы входит в мой вопрос, потому что без длины десятичного числа в битах ваш алгоритм не сработает

Comment: @Fanrin в ваш текущий вопрос, в том виде как он сформулирован, это не входит. Вы спрашиваете как записать некое число битов со смещение в некое число битов. Отсюда следует что длину и смещение вы уже знаете.

Comment: Я говорил про обычное число, а не число битов, и не со смещением, а именно в указанную область

Comment: @Fanrin Указанная область определяется чем? - правильно, смещением. Уточняйте вопрос и примеры.

Comment: Логично, что с 1 по 0 будет: (0 - 1) + 1, это 2. У нас есть число единиц, которое надо получить. А как теперь из 2 получить 0b11 (3), или из 3 получить 0b111 (7)

Comment: @Fanrin, а зачем "создавать" маску и знать ее длину? Маска создастся сама при применении битовых операторов к целому числу, а записать 7 битов в 3 позиции все равно не получится.

Comment: Я не упомянул про 7 битов, только 3 бита которые выражаются 0b111, которые число 7 в десятеричной

Answer (score 3):

Например, можно сделать следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::uint8_t b = 0b00001000;
    std::uint8_t b1 = ( ( ~0u << 4 ) & b ) | 0b0011;
    std::uint8_t b2 = ( ( ~0u << 2 ) & b ) | 0b0011;

    std::cout << "b = " << std::hex << ( int )b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b1 = " << std::hex << ( int )b1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b2 = " << std::hex << ( int )b2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
b = 8
b1 = 3
b2 = b
```

Можете написать отдельную функцию, как, например,

```
std::uint8_t replace( std::uint8_t src, std::uint8_t value, size_t bits )
{
    return ( ( ~0u << bits ) & src ) | ( ~( ~0u << bits ) & value );
}
```

Вот программа с использованием функции

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

std::uint8_t replace( std::uint8_t src, std::uint8_t value, size_t bits )
{
    return ( ( ~0u << bits ) & src ) | ( ~( ~0u << bits ) & value );
}

int main()
{
    std::uint8_t b = 0b00001000;
    std::uint8_t b1 = replace( b, 0b0011, 4 );
    std::uint8_t b2 = replace( b, 0b0011, 2 );

    std::cout << "b = " << std::hex << ( int )b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b1 = " << std::hex << ( int )b1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b2 = " << std::hex << ( int )b2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль точно такой же, как показано выше:

```
b = 8
b1 = 3
b2 = b
```

Если нужно задавать позицию, то функция может выглядеть следующим образом

```
std::uint8_t replace( std::uint8_t src, std::uint8_t value, size_t n, size_t pos )
{
    if ( n == 0 ) return src;

    return ( ( ~( ( 1u << n ) - 1) << pos ) & src ) | ( ~( ~0u << n ) & value );
}
```

Comment: А как используя вашу функцию записать нули, допустим, с 5 по 4 бит? Из байта 0b01100000 должно тогда получится 0b01000000

Comment: @Fanrin Задайте отдельный вопрос и получите ответ. В данном вашем вопросе все примеры касаются записи в младшие биты числа. Надо изначально полностью формулировать вопрос, а не изменять его условия при появлении ответов.

Comment: Я и не менял условие, просто хочу понять как у вас оно работает, мне надо заполнять область в байте, по хорошему в функции должно быть 4 аргумента: сам байт, число (которое надо записать в область), начало записи области, конец записи области.

Comment: @Fanrin Извините, я не заметил, что во втором примере вы используете индекс 1.  Да, в функции должен быть еще один аргумент, который указывает начало изменяемой области.

Comment: Или ещё наглядней пример, есть регистр с некоторыми настройками, вот http://code.re/91F и надо заполнить PCLK root divider, а это Bit[5:4]

Comment: @Fanrin Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: @Fanrin Если память не изменяет, то в книге Карниган и Ритчи "Программирование на C" есть решение такой задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте битовую арифметику.

Пусть есть две переменные `unsigned char` (по 8 бит в каждой, соответственно).

- `|` — побитовое 'или': `0b11 | 0b101 = 0b111`
- `&` — побитовое 'и': `0b11 & 0b101 = 0b1`
- `~` — побитовое 'не': `~0b11 = 0b11111100`
- `<<` — сдвиг влево: `0b101 << 2 = 0b10100`
- `>>` — сдвиг вправо: `0b1010 >> 2 = 0b10`

Теперь можно манипулировать битами числа. К примеру, для вашего случая:

```
unsigned char x = 0b00001000

x &= 0b11100001
// очистили место для вставки
// x = 0b00001000 & 0b11100001 = 0b00000000

x += (0b0011 << 1)
// x = 0b00000000 + (0b0011 << 1) =
//   = 0b00000000 + 0b00110 =
//   = 0b00000110
```

Comment: Вся проблема в том, чтобы создать маску для очистки исходя из условий

Answer (score 2):

Можно предложить несложную реализацию с побитовой обработкой вставки.

```
function masking($number,$mask,$start,$finish){
    $result=$number;
    for($i=$start; $i<=$finish; $i++){
        $bit=1<<$i;
        $result = ($result|$bit) - $bit + ($bit & $mask);
    }
    return $result;
}
$number=0b00001000; $mask=0b00000110;
$number_masked = masking($number,$mask,1,4);
printf("number=%b mask=%b start=%2d finish=%2d result=%b<br>", $number,       $mask, 1, 4, $number_masked);    
$mask=0b00000011;
$number_masked = masking($number,$mask,0,1);
printf("number=%b mask=%b start=%2d finish=%2d result=%b<br>", $number, $mask, 0, 1, $number_masked);
```

Результаты:

```
number=1000 mask=110 start= 1 finish= 4 result=110
number=1000 mask=11 start= 0 finish= 1 result=1011
```

Comment: Известно только число и его позиция которой он заполняет байт, маска не известна

Comment: Да, на самом деле маска (шаблон) - это те позиции исходного байта (от стартовой до финишной), в которые вставляется заплатка заказчика. Другое дело, что я предпочитаю вместо этой заплатки видеть целый байт, из которого вырезаются те же самые позиции.

Comment: Иными словами, переменную $mask мне следовало назвать $patch.

Answer (score 1):

Если можно избежать скучного вычисления битов, избегайте его. Пусть за вас считает компилятор. Воспользуйтесь именоваными структурами и битовыми полями.

(Да и наверняка структуры данных наподобие тех, которые я привёл, найдутся в документации.)

```
enum class PCLK_root_divider : unsigned char
{
    pll_clki_1 = 0,
    pll_clki_2 = 1,
    pll_clki_4 = 2,
    pll_clki_8 = 3
};

enum class sclk2x_root_divider : unsigned char
{
    pll_clki_1 = 0,
    pll_clki_2 = 1,
    pll_clki_4 = 2,
    pll_clki_8 = 3
};

enum class SCLK_root_divider : unsigned char
{
    pll_clki_1 = 0,
    pll_clki_2 = 1,
    pll_clki_4 = 2,
    pll_clki_8 = 3
};

struct Whatever
{
    SCLK_root_divider _SCLK_root_divider : 2;
    sclk2x_root_divider _sclk2x_root_divider : 2;
    PCLK_root_divider _PCLK_root_divider : 2;
    unsigned char _debug_mode : 2;
};
```

Только дайте полям какие-то более подходящие имена.

Важно: не забывайте про big/little endian! Порядок полей может быть противоположным на другой архитектуре.

Проверка: http://ideone.com/RfRrk2

Comment: Просто в устройстве очень много регистров (около 70 тысяч), сложно будет для всего создавать структуры

Comment: @Fanrin: А вычислять правильные битовые оффсеты для 70 тысяч регистров будет, думаете, проще?

Answer (score 0):

Если отметить область вставки единичными битами шаблона ($template), а саму вставку задать в виде байта ($patch), в котором "свои" биты находятся на требуемых позициях, то результат получается в одну строчку:

```
function patching($number, $patch, $template){
    return $number & (255-$template) | $patch & $template;
}
printf("number=%08b patch=%08b template=%08b result=%08b<br>", 
    $number=0b00001000, $patch=0b00000110, $template=0b00011110, patching($number, $patch, $template));
printf("number=%08b patch=%08b template=%08b result=%08b<br>", 
    $number=0b00001000, $patch=0b00000011, $template=0b0000011, patching($number, $patch, $template));
```

Результаты:

```
number=00001000 patch=00000110 template=00011110 result=00000110
number=00001000 patch=00000011 template=00000011 result=00001011
```

При этом гибкость процедуры повышается, поскольку вставляемые байты не обязаны находиться рядом.